# Linux scripting - how do I wait for CD/DVD medium to load before reading/mounting?

Tags: linux, shell, mount, optical-media

I'm putting together a quick-and-dirty script to read 100s of CD/DVDs onto a NAS. It takes care of ejecting and loading the tray, but I haven't figured out a simple way to wait/block for the medium to become available to the OS after inserting the tray.

- `eject -t` exits as soon as the tray closes
- `mount` will fail with *No medium found* if it's run immediately after `eject`, but also when it's run 15 seconds later.

The discs are fairly old and some take considerable time to become available, so I'd like to avoid the "sleep for 2 minutes" non-solution. Any ideas? Using ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: On most distros, there's a fairly complicated system of udev rules which try to identify a CD as soon as it becomes available. Try to hook into those rules, or see if they emit DBUS events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this do?

```
while ! dd if=/dev/sr2 bs=2048 count=1 of=/dev/null 2>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

Replace `/dev/sr2` with your actual cd/dvd device.

You can make it more robust by checking for errors other than `No medium found`; untested, since I don't have any broken DVD at hand:

```
dev=/dev/sr2
while :; do
        err=$(dd if=$dev of=/dev/null bs=2048 status=none count=1 2>&1)
        case $err in
        "dd: failed to open '$dev': No medium found")
                sleep 1 ;;
        '')
                # successfully opened
                break ;;
        *)
                # unexpected error
                # play some SOUND in the speakers
                # and wait for user input to continue
                read wtf ;;
        esac
done
```

**Update:**

On drives that support it, linux will automatically close the tray on trying to open the device. While this could probably be disabled by `ioctl(CDROM_CLEAR_OPTIONS, CDO_AUTO_CLOSE)`, I wasn't able to find any command line utility implementing it. Since that forces one to use `C`, better use `C` for the whole thing.

So, here's a small application that can check and poll for the cd/dvd drive status.

If called with a single argument:

```
cdstatus /dev/sr1
```

it will print the status of `/dev/sr1`: one of `no_disc`, `tray_open`, `drive_not_ready` or `disc_ok`.

If called with two arguments:

```
cdstatus /dev/sr1 1.3
```

it will poll `/dev/sr1` every 1.3 seconds until its status is `disk_ok`.

It could be easily built with `cc -Os -Wall cdstatus.c -s -o cdstatus`, provided that the gcc and libc6-dev packages are installed.

**cdstatus.c**

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/cdrom.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <poll.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv){
        int fd, s; int pt = -1;
        if(argc < 2)
                errx(1, "usage: %s /dev/srX [poll_secs] [verbose]", argv[0]);
        if((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK)) == -1)
                err(1, "open %s", argv[1]);
        if(argc > 2 && ((pt = strtod(argv[2], 0) * 1000) < 1 || pt > 3600000))
                errx(1, "bad timeout '%s'", argv[2]);
redo:
        switch(s = ioctl(fd, CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS, 0)){
        case -1: err(1, "ioctl(CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS)");
        case CDS_NO_INFO: errx(1, "ioctl(CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS) not implemented");
        }
        if(pt < 0 || argc > 3)
                switch(s){
                case CDS_NO_DISC: printf("no_disc\n"); break;
                case CDS_TRAY_OPEN: printf("tray_open\n"); break;
                case CDS_DRIVE_NOT_READY: printf("drive_not_ready\n"); break;
                case CDS_DISC_OK: printf("disc_ok\n"); break;
                default: printf("status=%d\n", s); break;
                }
        if(pt > 0 && s != CDS_DISC_OK){
                if(poll(0, 0, pt) < 0) err(1, "poll");
                goto redo;
        }
        return s != CDS_DISC_OK;
}
```

Comment: ... almost.  However in my case it also closes an open DVD/CD drive platter.  I was looking for a way to detect a DVD/CD after a User has closed the drive.

Comment: I have updated the answer -- if that's not an option for you, it may at least give you some hints on what to google for.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, a [post in this vaguely-related thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/view-optical-media-and-optical-drive-information-in-cli-942882/#post5314393) on linuxquestions suggested to use `wodim -atip` (among other things) which turns out to work great to block until the medium is available.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

DRIVE=${DRIVE:-"sr0"}
DESTROOT=${DESTROOT:-"/mnt/newshare"}
DRV_FULLNAME="$(</sys/class/block/$DRIVE/device/vendor) $(</sys/class/block/$DRIVE/device/model)"

[ -d /tmp/$DRIVE ] || mkdir /tmp/$DRIVE
while true; do
  eject /dev/$DRIVE
  echo "$DRV_FULLNAME is ready."
  read -p "Enter next disc code: " DISC
  if [ -z "$DISC" ]; then
    echo "No disc code = we're done, exiting"
    break
  fi
  eject -t /dev/$DRIVE || {
    read -n1 -r -p "Unable to load tray. Push it in and hit Any key..."
    echo
  }
  wodim dev=/dev/$DRIVE -atip > /dev/null || {
    echo "Medium not detected."
    break
  }
  mount /dev/$DRIVE /tmp/$DRIVE -o ro ||  {
    echo "Couldn't mount medium."
    break
  }
  cp -ia /tmp/$DRIVE/. $DESTROOT/$DISC/ || {
    echo "COPY FAILED. Put it on the read-error pile and continue with next one."
  }
done
```

Comment: I wouldn't use that. There's no guarantee that `wodim` command won't simply return with an error. It's a race game. Please also consider my [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477629/314839). And if I was you, I wouldn't try to mount the cd/dvds on the device-- I would rather `dd` all of them whole into `.iso` images in some dir, and then process them leasurely (mount them with `-o loop`, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Re: mounting and copying - no worries. The discs are well sorted and the largest group are things where copying files is the right thing to do. ;-)

Re: `wodim` race game - oops, I seem to have put the error handler in the wrong place. Will edit that.

I have seen your answer and thanks for the case-based error handler, but I was looking for a one-liner that would avoid looping.